# Adjusting ggplot legend and values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot where the legend is overlaying one of the graphs, though I'm not sure how to not overlay the legend over the graphs. Furthermore, is there a way to scale the smaller values on the plot so they can all be seen, as some are only presented as a straight line towards 0?

perhaps, labeling the lines with their respective legend names right next to the graph would be more appropriate? Expected likeso:
[image]

Here's what my graph looks like:
[image]

My code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Set3"))
myPal <- cols(length(unique(test.t.land$ly_name)))

forestlossline <- ggplot(test.t.land, aes(x=factor(year), y=pland, group=ly_name, label=round(pland, 1))) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=ly_name)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=ly_name), shape = 21, size = 2, colour="black", stroke = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=myPal) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=myPal)+
  ylab("AREA IN SQUARE KILOMETERS") +
  xlab("YEAR") +
  facet_wrap(~lc_name, scales="free") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("year")+
  theme(
    axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold", size=13, family="TT Times New Roman"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold", size=13, family="TT Times New Roman"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face="bold", size =10, family="TT Times New Roman", angle=90), 
    axis.text.y=element_text(face="bold",  size =10, family="TT Times New Roman"),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.text=element_text(color="black", size =10, face="bold", family="TT Times New Roman"),
    legend.justification=c(1.2,1),
    legend.position=c(1,0.2),
    plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size = 18, hjust=0.5, colour = "black"),
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    legend.key.height=unit(.1, "cm")
  )
```

Reproducible code:

```
test.t.land <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/test/main/example.html"
library(rvest)
test.t.land<- as.data.frame(read_html(test.t.land) %>% html_table(fill=TRUE))
test.t.land <- test.t.land[,-1]
```

Comment: I can't replicate your data. But looking at your ggplot code, I think all you need is to remove this line:     `legend.position=c(1,0.2)`
That is the one that is placing the legend in a custom position.
Perhaps you copy-pasted this code from a facet_wrap() that had an empty space in the lower right corner?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez I have updated the code which should be working now. Although, your mention did fix the problem with the legend. Thanks!

Comment: @tjebo - my mistake, thanks for catching that! Removed my erroneous comment.